# If Else-if in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, testing, if-statement, automated-tests, robotframework

I want get value from a Keyword by using else if.

Example:

```
String text = ""  
If variable > 5
   text = "one";
else if variable <5
   text = "two";
else
   text = "three";
```

---

In Robot Framework

I use the code

```
${txt}    Set Variable
${txt}=    Run Keyword If    ${length} > 5    Some Keyword
\    ELSE IF    ${length} < 5    Some Keyword
\    ELSE    Some Keyword
Log       ${txt}
```

---

ERROR !!!

```
In Keyword ELSE IF  ;  Keyword name cannot be empty
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add **THREE DOTS** (...) in first cell before ELSE IF keyword

```
${txt}    Set Variable
${txt}=    Run Keyword If    ${lenght} > 5    Some Keyword
...    ELSE IF    ${lenght} < 5    Some Keyword
...    ELSE    Some Keyword
Log       ${txt}
```

Comment: The Solution working for running keywords but when a variable is declared inside ELSE IF or ELSE then it is returning error. Ex: If a variable like ${a}=  1 is declared inside ELSE IF and on doing log to console  ${a} returning "Variable '${a}' not found."

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to code this with Robot Framework's version of a switch statement is:

```
*** Variables ***    
String  ${text} =  ""

*** Keywords ***
${text} =  Set Variable If
...  ${variable} > 5  one
...  ${variable} < 5  two
...  ${variable} = 5  three
```

There may be other ways using Run Keyword If and Run Keyword Unless.

Answer (score 1):

Since since robot 4.0, native IF else support is available. You can refer below example:

```
IF  '${status}' == 'true'
    ${i}  Set Variable  10
    log to console  inside if
ELSE IF  '${status}' == 'false'
    ${i}  Set Variable  20
    log to console  inside else if
ELSE
    ${i}  Set Variable  30
    log to console  inside else
END
```